# Django Dataframe not able to convert timestamp to date

Tags: python, django, pandas, dataframe

Django Data frame not able to convert timestamp to date in template view

Query result of **Select * from paper_trade where date = now()::date order by open_time** is

```
Date        day    open_time
2022-10-19  Wednesday  10:54
```

My code is as below

```
sql_query_n = pd.read_sql_query("""Select * from paper_trade where date = now()::date order by open_time""",con=engine)
df_n = pd.DataFrame(sql_query_n)
json_records_n = df_n.reset_index().to_json(orient ='records')
data_n = []
data_n = json.loads(json_records_n)
```

In the django template trying to itrate and use as **{{ i.date }}**

Date_______________day_________        open_time
1666137600000   Wednesday   1666176843000
1666137600000   Wednesday   1666185662000
1666137600000   Wednesday   1666188004000

Tried **{{ i.date|date:'Y-m-d' }}** but it gives empty value. What is the issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the column manually;

Example (from my own codebase):

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=analytics)
if df.empty:
    return Response([])

df = df[df.columns.drop(list(df.filter(regex='Unnamed')))]
date_range = pd.date_range(
            **get_min_max_date_range_from_dataframe(
                df=df,
                date_key='date',
            )
        )
df.set_index(['date'], inplace=True)
df = df.reindex(date_range, fill_value=0)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.rename(columns={"index": "date"}, inplace=True)

dict_df = df.to_dict('records')
for rec in dict_df:
    # Here's how you convert the date to string
    rec['date'] = str(rec['date'].to_pydatetime().date())
```

Comment: I am trying to manage with javascript